# Datatable Fixed header does not scroll when first 2 columns are also fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a Datatable with fixed header on vertical scroll and first 2 columns fixed on horizontal scroll.When I scroll down vertically and then try to horizontally scroll the datatable. The headers don't scroll according to the data(headers remain fixed). Can someone help me on this?

Here is the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a419nurq/)

JS Code:

```
 var table = $('#example').DataTable({
     "iDisplayLength": 50,
     "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],           
     "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],        
     "scrollX": true,
     "scrollCollapse": true,
     "fixedColumns": {
         "leftColumns": 2,
     },
     "sScrollXInner": "150%",
     "fixedHeader": true,         
     "drawCallback": function (settings) {
         var api = this.api();
         var visibleRows = api.rows({ page: 'current' }).data();
     },          
 });
```

Comment: And you did not notice the detail "**Please note that FixedHeader is not currently compatible with tables that have the scrolling features of DataTables enabled**" when you read the documentation over and over, before asking here on SO? :)